# Menu bar items do not take up the same width (HTML/CSS)

Tags: css, html, position

**Goal:** I would like the menu items to take up the same amount of space in regards to each other. When stretching the display space, I would not like menu items to collapse to their own line.  Instead, I would like them to get closer and closer together.

---

**attempt 1:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<style>
    #container{
        width: 100%;
    }


    #navigation{
        width: 100%;
        background: #333;
        display: table;
    }
    #navigation ul{
        margin:0px auto;
        padding: 0 0 0 0;
        display: table-row;

    }
    #navigation li{
        list-style-type: none;
        display: inline;
        display: table-cell;
    }
    #navigation li a{
        float: left;
        /*padding: 5px 10.2%;*/
        padding: 5px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #navigation li a:hover{ 
        background: #1C5EC2; 
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Home"        >Home</a>        </li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Games"       >Games</a>       </li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="High Scores" >High Scores</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Contact Us"  >Contact Us</a>  </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Although these items all stay together horizontally, they are not equally spaced apart.  Also, highlighting over them does not shade as wide of an area as I would like.

---

**attempt 2:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<style>
    #container{
        width: 100%;
    }


    #navigation{
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        background: #333;
    }
    #navigation ul{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #navigation ul li{
        list-style-type: none;
        display: inline;
    }
    #navigation li a{
        display: inline;
        float: left;
        padding: 5px 10.3%;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    #navigation li a:hover { background: #1C5EC2; }
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Home"        >Home</a>        </li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Games"       >Games</a>       </li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="High Scores" >High Scores</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Contact Us"  >Contact Us</a>  </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This example is almost exactly what I want.  Everything about this is correct, except that stretching the display size smaller puts menu items on a line below the other items.

---

How can I can I take the non-wrapping behavior of the first attempt, and apply it to my second attempt?  My goal is to have a working implementation of the 2nd attempt that does not wrap menu items.

*note: i have separate CSS files and html involved, but I included only what I think is needed for the problem. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here - I've made a fiddle.  Is this what you are looking for?
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/5mErT/18/)

I've changed the CSS for your `li` and `a` elements:

```
#navigation ul li {

    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;    
    text-align: center;
}


#navigation li a {

    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    display: block;    
}
```

Comment: This is awesome! Two problems: (1) you need to know the number of elements you have to set the width correctly; (2) an odd number of elements (e.g., 3 elements @ 33% width) leaves some unused space on the right.

Comment: @gordian - you can do better than integer precision with your width spec... so you could just do 33.333333% width and it would fill in perfectly.

Comment: But you still need to set a value for the width which depends on the number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [oksushi](https://gist.github.com/oksushi/3754361/), this will do it without having to set the width and without extra space at the end:

### http://jsfiddle.net/VBcUM/

### HTML

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Dolor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sit</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Amet</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Consectetur</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Adipiscing</a></li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
ul {
  padding: 0;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
li {
  display: table-cell;
}
a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
}
a:hover {
  background: lime;
}
```